# code reaching to timed out in telnet and ssh def

Tags: python, python-2.7, telnetlib

Please help in this code. Its working if using telnet and ssh code without function. Meaning if reiterating telnet and ssh code where ever is needed then its working. But after created separate function for both is not able to telnet or ssh and showing timed out after highlighted points.

```
import os
import paramiko
import telnetlib
import time
import getpass
import Crypto.Cipher.AES
#################################################################################
def ssHNet(host1,user1,pass1,cli):
    ip=host1
    id=user1
    password=pass1
    command=cli
    print ip + id + password + command
    print "ssh'ing......!!!"+" >> "+ip #### after this line getting timed out error. 
    t1=paramiko.Transport((ip,22))
    t1.connect(username=id,password=password)
    channel_four=t1.open_session()
    channel_four.exec_command(command)
    response=channel_four.recv("5000")
    print response
    t1.close()
##################################################################################
##################################################################################
def TeleNet(host1,user1,pass1,cli):
    host=host1
    user=user1
    password=pass1
    command=cli
    print "Telnet'ing_inside def"+" >> "+host     ##### after this line getting timed out error. 
    telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(host,23,10) 
    telnet.read_until(': ', 3)
    telnet.write(user.encode('ascii') + '\r')
    telnet.read_until('Password: ', 3)
    telnet.write(password.encode('ascii') + '\r')
    telnet.write('terminal length 0' + '\r\n')
    telnet.write(command)
    print telnet.read_all()
    telnet.write('exit' + '\r\n')
##################################################################################
##################################################################################
def addressInNetwork(ip, net):
   import socket,struct
   ipaddr = int(''.join([ '%02x' % int(x) for x in ip.split('.') ]), 16)
   netstr, bits = net.split('/')
   netaddr = int(''.join([ '%02x' % int(x) for x in netstr.split('.') ]), 16)
   mask = (0xffffffff << (32 - int(bits))) & 0xffffffff
   return (ipaddr & mask) == (netaddr & mask)
##################################################################################
##################################################################################
orig_new = Crypto.Cipher.AES.new
def fixed_AES_new(key, *ls):
      if Crypto.Cipher.AES.MODE_CTR == ls[0]:
       ls = list(ls)
       ls[1] = ''
      return orig_new(key, *ls)
##################################################################################
##################################################################################
def telnetcall(host1,user1,pass1):
        try:
        host=host1
        user1=user1
        pass1=pass1
                print "Telnet'ing_01"+" >> "+host
        cli = 'show version' + '\r\n'
        TeleNet(host1,user1,pass1,cli)
                if "Cisco IOS" in a:
                        print "Telnet'ing_02"+" >> "+host
            cli = 'show run | begin line con' + '\r\n'
            TeleNet(host1, user1, pass1, cli)
                        if "line 2" in b:
                                output = host+" Line 2 is there"
                                cpeconsolidated_output.write(output)
                                cpeconsolidated_output.write("\n")
                TeleNet(host1, user1, pass1)
                                template_open = open("modify_line2.txt")
                                template_read = template_open.readlines()
                                print template_read
                                template_open.close()
                                for sh_cmd in template_read:
                                        print sh_cmd
                                        time.sleep(2)
                                        telnet.write(sh_cmd)
                                        output1 = telnet.read_very_eager()
                                        print output1
                                        time.sleep(2)
                                telnet.write('exit' + '\r\n')
                                print output
                        else:
                                output = host+" *******Line 2 is not there******"
                                cpeconsolidated_output.write(output)
                                cpeconsolidated_output.write("\n")
                                print output
        except Exception as detail:
        print detail
##################################################################################
##################################################################################
def sshcall(host1,user1,pass1):
        try:
        show1='terminal length 0'
        ssHNet(host1,user1,pass1,show1)
        show1='show version'
        platform=ssHNet(host1, user1, pass1,show1)
                time.sleep(5)
                if "Cisco IOS" in platform:
            show1='show run | begin line con'
            line2=ssHNet(host1, user1, pass1,show1)
                        if "line 2" in line2:
                                output = host1+" Line 2 is there (SSH)"
                                cpeconsolidated_output.write(output)
                                cpeconsolidated_output.write("\n")
                                ssh_dev=host1
                                usr = user1
                                pwd = pass1
                                template_open = open("modify_line2.txt")
                                template_read = template_open.readlines()
                                print template_read
                                template_open.close()
                                remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
                                remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                                remote_conn_pre.connect(ssh_dev, username=usr, password=pwd, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
                                remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
                                for sh_cmd in template_read:
                                        print sh_cmd
                                        time.sleep(2)
                                        remote_conn.send(sh_cmd)
                                        time.sleep(2)
                                        output1 = remote_conn.recv(50000)
                    print output1
                print output
                        else:
                                output = host1+" *Line 2 is not there (SSH)"
                                cpeconsolidated_output.write(output)
                                print output
                                cpeconsolidated_output.write("\n")
        except Exception as detail:
        print detail
##################################################################################
##################################################################################
ippermnet01='212.74.0.0/16'
ippermnet02='10.0.0.0/8'
Crypto.Cipher.AES.new = fixed_AES_new
txtopen = open("cpeweekacl.txt")
iplist = txtopen.readlines()
txtopen.close()
cpeopen = open("cpekernaloutput.txt","w+")
cpeconsolidated_output = open("cpeconsolidated_output.txt","w+")
j=len(iplist)
username = "test_user"
password = "test_password"
for i in range(0,j):
        ippermlist=iplist[i].strip()
        telnetstr = "nc -zv "+ippermlist+" 23"+" "+"&>> cpekernaloutput.txt"
        sshstr = "nc -zv "+ippermlist+" 22"+" "+"&>> cpekernaloutput.txt"
        os.system(telnetstr)
        cpeopen_temp = cpeopen.read()
        connected_telnet = "Connected to "+ippermlist+":23"
        if (addressInNetwork(ippermlist, ippermnet01) or addressInNetwork(ippermlist, ippermnet02)) == True:
                print ippermlist+" Check Host is not in scope P1"
    elif (addressInNetwork(ippermlist, ippermnet01) and addressInNetwork(ippermlist, ippermnet02)) == False:
                if connected_telnet in cpeopen_temp:
                        telnetcall(ippermlist,username,password)
                else:
                        sshcall(ippermlist,username,password)
        else:
                print ippermlist+" Check Host is not in scope P1"
##################################################################################
##################################################################################
cpeconsolidated_output.close()
cpeopen.close()
txtopen.close()
```

Please help in this code. Its working if using telnet and ssh code without function. Meaning if reiterating telnet and ssh code where ever is needed then its working. But after created separate function for both is not able to telnet or ssh and showing timed out after highlighted points.

Comment: Request you to please respond as early as possible. I need this code to execute asap. Please help in this code. Its working if using telnet and ssh code without function. Meaning if reiterating telnet and ssh code where ever is needed then its working. But after created separate function for both is not able to telnet or ssh and showing timed out after highlighted points.

Comment: Please debug your code, break it further down, until it works again. Your indentation looks off as well, maybe this causes a problem?